On 3 centers of triangles
We add a little to On two centers of convex regions
For any interior point $P$ in a planar convex region $C$, we define d_max to be the maximum distance from $P$ to the boundary of $C$ (distance from $P$ to the farthest point on the boundary of $C$ from it) and d_min to be min distance from $P$ to the boundary. We consider 3 quantities:

the 'distance ratio', d_min/ d_max. We look for the position of $P$ that maximizes its value.

the 'distance product', d_max d_min and find the position of $P$ that maximizes it.

the 'distance difference', d_max - d_min and find the position of $P$ that minimizes it.


When $C$ is a triangle, our numerical calculations indicate: the distance ratio and distance product appear to have maximum value always at the incenter of the triangle. We couldn't find the point that minimizes the distance difference (it is not the incenter or centroid; not sure if the point is unique when $C$ is a triangle).
Question: Can the above observations be justified? Which point minimizes the distance difference?
Note 1: Numerically, we also see that the incentre is at least a local maximum (maybe even the global max) also for the harmonic mean of d_max and d_min (that the incenter probably maximizes their geometric mean was noted above). The arithmetic mean of d_max and d_min appears to have a max value on the boundary of the triangle (and of course, increases without bound outwards) so interior point(s) minimizing it might be more interesting.
Note 2: Moving on from triangles to general convex regions, we can ask (say) if the position of the optimum of any of the above  quantities is unique, what can one say about the shape of $C$?
Note 3: The interior optimal points for each of the above quantities when $C$ is an ellipse could also be of interest.

My mistake: I hadn't noticed that that one was a minimisation rather than a maximisation.

thank you. deleting my earlier comment... edited the post emphasizing the 'minimization'

Hi, i do not know maybe i am missing things, with distance from a point to a line considered as an orthogonal projection; in this case isn't points 1 and 3 trivial for the incenter?

I understand $d_{\min}\le d_{\max}$, and with equality for $P$  incenter...

While it is true that d_min is maximized at the incenter, what the question seeks is the interior points maximizing various combinations of d_min and d_max.

Thank you, but $d_{\max}-d_{\min}\ge 0$ it is equal zero (the minimum) only for $P$ the incenter. Either that or you consider a distance as any segment joining $P$ to the boundary? (this may be said differently as for "distance")

@ToniMhax I presumed that the latter is the case, since the question talks about minimum and maximum distances from a point $P$ to the boundary of the convex region $C$; the minimum distance will always be a projection down to one of the edges of the triangle, but the maximum distance will always be to a corner.

@StevenStadnicki, yes that is probably the only way, but the name distance should be changed, in geometry we know the distance is related to orthogonal projections...

Thanks. I understand the confusion now. Added a clarification in the question.

The distance ratio and distance product are indeed maximized for the incenter.

Let $I$ be the incenter, $r$ the inradius, $\angle BAC=\alpha$ the minimal angle, then the distance ratio $\operatorname{dr} (I)$ equals $\frac{r}{AI}=\sin \alpha/2$. For arbitrary point $P$ in the triangle, one of angles $\angle BAP$ or $\angle CAP$ is at most $\alpha/2$, without loss of generality $\angle BAP\leqslant \alpha/2$. Denote by $Q$ the foot of perpendicular from $P$ to the line $BA$. Then $PQ=PA\sin \angle BAP\leqslant PA\sin \alpha/2$. Also, the minimal distance from $P$ to the boundary of $\triangle ABC$ does not exceed $PQ$ (since the segment $PQ$ always contains a boundary point, although not necessarily this point is $Q$). The maximal distance from $P$ to the boundary of $\triangle ABC$ is not less than $PA$. Thus, $\operatorname{dr} (P)\leqslant PQ/PA\leqslant \sin \alpha/2=\operatorname{dr} (I)$.

Let $P$ be a point in $\triangle ABC$ which maximizes the distance product $\operatorname{dp} (P)$, it exists by the compactness argument and is an interior point since $\operatorname{dp}$ vanishes on the boundary. We want to prove $P=I$. Assume the contrary. Denote by $t$ the minimal distance from $P$ to the boundary of $\triangle ABC$. The circle $\omega$ centered in $P$ of radius $t$ is contained in $\triangle ABC$ and has a common point with its boundary. Thus, it is tangent to at least one side of $\triangle ABC$. Consider three cases:


a) $\omega$ is tangent to all sides of $\triangle ABC$. Then $P=I$ as needed.
b) $\omega$ is tangent to only one side of $\triangle ABC$, say, to $AB$. Let $X\in \{A,B,C\}$ be the most distant from $P$ vertex of $\triangle ABC$. We may move slightly shift $P$ by a vector parallel to $AB$ in one of two opposite directions so that $PX$ strictly increases, and the circle centered in $P$ of radius $t$ still is contained in $\triangle ABC$. Then $\operatorname{dp}(P)$ strictly increases, a contradiction.
c) $\omega$ is tangent to two sides of $\triangle ABC$, say, to $AB$ and $AC$. This means that $P$ lies on the segment $AI$. If the most distant from $P$ vertex of $\triangle ABC$ is $A$, then moving $P$ to $I$ makes both the maximal and the minimal distance to the boundary of $\triangle ABC$ larger, so, $\operatorname{dp}(P)$ increases, that is impossible. So, without loss of generality the most distant from $P$ vertex of $\triangle ABC$ is $B$. In particular, $PB\geqslant PA$ that is equivalent to $\varphi:=\angle PBA\leqslant \angle PAB=\alpha/2$. Also, $\varphi\leqslant IBA=:\beta/2$. Let a point $Q$ move from $A$ along the ray $AI$ until $\theta:=\angle QBI$ becomes equal to $\min(\alpha/2,\beta/2)$. I claim
Proposition. $f(\theta):=QB\cdot QB\sin \theta$ increases on the segment $[0,\min(\alpha/2,\beta/2)]$.
Since $f(\varphi)$ is nothing but $\operatorname{dp}(P)$, Proposition yields $\operatorname{dp}(P)\leqslant f(\min(\alpha/2,\beta/2))$. If $\min(\alpha/2,\beta/2)=\beta/2$, this immediately gives $\operatorname{dp}(P)\leqslant r\cdot PB\leqslant \operatorname{dp}(I)$, as needed. If $\min(\alpha/2,\beta/2)=\alpha/2$, the point $Q=Q_0$ with $\theta=\alpha/2$ on the segment $AI$ enjoys the equality $Q_0A=Q_0B$, thus $f(\alpha/2)=Q_0A^2\sin \alpha/2\leqslant IA^2\sin\alpha/2=IA\cdot r\leqslant \operatorname{dp}(I)$.
So, it remains to prove Proposition. We have by Sine law $QB=BA\cdot \frac{\sin \alpha/2}{\sin(\alpha/2+\theta)}$, thus,
$$(\log f(\theta))'=\cot\theta-2\cot(\alpha/2+\theta)\geqslant \cot\theta-2\cot 2\theta=\frac1{\cot \theta}\geqslant 0.$$

The first proof feels particularly nice and simple! Thanks. Look forward to answers to the other questions too - points minimizing the difference between d_max and d_min and their AM and also proof whether the HM too has a max at the incenter. Marking the question as 'answered'.

We can easily enough look at a slightly non-trivial case, an isosceles right triangle: set the vertices are at $(0, 0)$, $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$. Then $d_{\mathrm max}$ will always be the distance between a point and one of the three vertices (this will in fact be the case for any triangle), and in this case the origin can never be the (unique) farthest vertex, so we can separate the triangle into the regions $x>=y$ and $y>x$, and by symmetry we only have to look at the first. $d_{\mathrm min}$ will always be the orthogonal distance to an edge of the triangle; given the restricted region we're looking at, that edge can never be the vertical edge of the triangle so we only have to look at the distances to the x axis and to the line $x+y=1$ and compare those. The two regimes are separated by the bisector of the $\pi/4$ angle at $(1, 0)$; that is to say, the line $y=(\sqrt{2}-1)(1-x)$.

Now, in the lower part of this region (the triangle ${\bigtriangleup}ABE$) it's easy to see that E has both the smallest $d_{\mathrm max}$ and the largest $d_{\mathrm min}$, so it must be the minimizer of this distance in that region. In the upper part ${\bigtriangleup}BDE$ it's easy to see that any point in the interior projects to a point on the segment $DE$ with smaller $d_{\mathrm max}$ and equal $d_{\mathrm min}$, so the minimum of the difference must be on this segment; then labeling the distance along this segment from $D$ as $d$, we have $d_\mathrm{min}=d$ and $d_\mathrm{max}=\sqrt{\ell^2+d^2}$ for some $\ell$ (specifically the distance $|CD|$) so the difference is $\sqrt{\ell^2+d^2}-d$, which decreases as $d$ increases; thus $E$ is the minimum in this region as well. This means that the center by this metric is at $E$, where $y=x$ and $y=(\sqrt{2}-1)(1-x)$ intersect. As the intersection of the angle bisectors of the triangle this is also the incenter in this case; I'm not confident that will be the case generically, but since the minimizer of $d_\mathrm{edge}$ between two edges will always be along the angle bisector I wouldn't be surprised.
